# Batch file relative path to current dir

Tags: batch-file

I'm doing some BATCH scripting looping through files to copy. But I came to a problem where I need the path relative to the current .bat execution folder (%cd%)

So if I have files like this:

- c:\games\batchTest\test.bat
- c:\games\batchTest\subFolder1\test1.txt

How can I get just "subFolder1\test1.txt" so I can copy the file with the sub folder?

My current code:

```
for /r %%a in (*) do ( 

echo "%%a"

)
```

Comment: in cmd.exe, type For /?

Read the information regarding expanding path related variables during For loops.

Comment: Copying should work the same with a full path as it would a relative one. Perhaps you should explain your task with more detail.

Comment: I'm trying to copy all files from folderA to folderB, keeping the sub directories

Comment: Also I need to filter out some files

Comment: You may not need a `for` loop or relative paths. I you open up a Command Prompt window and enter both `xcopy /?` and `robocooy /?`, read through their usage information and choose whichever of them you wish, it may be sufficient for your needs. `Robocopy` is the newer, and was built to supercede `xcopy`, so I'd recommend that if you're unsure.

Comment: Let us first clarify if you really need a path relative to __current directory__ or a path relative to __directory containing the batch file Test.bat__ because of these are two different things. I suggest to read the Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file) to get knowledge how to reference a file/folder relative to __current directory__. `%~dp0` expands on execution of a batch file to full path of the batch file always ending with a backslash, see `echo "%~dp0subFolder1\test1.txt"` in your batch file.

Comment: I suggest to open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cd /D "%TEMP%"` to make the directory for temporary files the current directory and run next `C:\games\batchTest\test.bat`. If your batch file `test.bat` contains the lines `echo Current directory: "%CD%"` and `echo Batch file directory: "%~dp0"`, you can see now the important difference. `%CD%` expands to a string not ending with a backslash, except the current directory is the root directory of a drive. `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 - the batch file itself) expands to a string always ending with ``\``.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
@Echo Off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
For /r %%a In (*) Do (
  Set p="%%a"
  Echo !p:%__CD__%=!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`for /R` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) always returns absolute paths, even if the (optional) given root directory behind `/R` is relative.

A possible way to get relative paths is to (mis-)use the [`xcopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) together with its `/L` option that prevents anything to be copied:

```cmd
xcopy /L /S /I ".\*.*" "%TEMP%"
```

To remove the summary line `# File(s)` apply a filter using [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) using a [pipe](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
xcopy /L /S /I ".\*.*" "%TEMP%" | find ".\"
```

To process the returned items use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```cmd
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    xcopy /L /S /I ".\*.*" "%TEMP%" ^| find ".\"
') do (
    echo Processing file "%%F"...
)
```

---

If you just want to copy files including the sub-directory structure you do not even need the above stuff with `for` loops, you can simply use `xcopy`:

```cmd
xcopy /S /I "D:\Source\*.*" "D:\Destination"
```

or [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

```cmd
robocopy /S "D:\Source" "D:\Destination" "*.*"
```